# ImageView is being pushed off screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a layout problem with Android xml. I am sorry if this is a noob question but xml is magic to me although I know it really shouldn't

Anyway, here is the layout file that is making trouble (content_activity_deal_creation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.DealCreationActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_deal_creation">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDealCreation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/priceInput"
        android:hint="@string/price"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/storeEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dealDescriptionEditText"
        android:hint="@string/deal_description"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewDealCreation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/dealTitleEditText"
        android:hint="@string/title_deal_deal_creation"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dealDescriptionEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/storeEditText"
        android:hint="@string/store"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dealTitleEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: This is what is looks like when rendered by the phone]

This is the activit_deal_creation.xml that is being included:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.DealCreationActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_activity_deal_creation" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It only gets worse when I take a picture and put it in the ImageView. Then only about half the piture is visible.
What is it that I am missing here? It has to be possible to put in on screen normally.

I appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

The Code above inculed the solution from the accepted answer below. 
Thank you for your help. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Set `android:fillViewPort="true"` for `ScrollView`

Comment: probably it is your toolbar which is hiding your image. set your image below the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason

First thing is that your `ImageView` is not pushed off screen. It is still on screen but covered with the `AppBarLayout`.

Normally `CoordinatorLayout` does layout the same way as `FrameLayout`, this means in your case all direct children will occupy entire height (`match_parent`) and will be layered, one on top of each other, but with `CoordinatorLayout` is a bit different. You see `AppBarLayout` on top of your `ScrollView` because it has a default dependency applied (`AppBarLayout.Behavior`) and `CoordinatorLayout` draws everything not in a regular order, but according to the dependency chain.

### Solution

You have to add this behavior to your `ScrollView`. Then it will be drawn below the `AppBarLayout`, not covered by it.

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

**Note**:  you've declared this behavior in `RelativeLayout`, but it will not work. Behaviors work only when declared on direct children of `CoordinatorLayout`. You can read more about the details in this post [Intercepting everything with CoordinatorLayout Behaviors](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#.p81jcpkmn).

Answer (score 1):

Set up your XML as outlined in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) for `AppBarLayout` including changing out `ScrollView` for `NestedScrollView`. My understanding is that `ScrollView` does not work with `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in `@layout/activity_deal_creation` - you are including this view probbably in `FrameLayout` or other container that puts `Toolbar` on top of the scroll view. You'd need to change it there to have your `ScrollView` *below* the toolbar in Y axis

Comment: As I understand it, I have the Entire View below the toolbar. I have posted the other xml for reference too.

Comment: What if you use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately. Same result